# Why am I getting this error in Python? TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not tuple

Tags: python

I Keep getting the same error, and I can't figure out how to make it work.
[Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOe2H.png)

Comment: You're trying to check if that tuple of strings is in a single string, and python can't understand that. You need something like `any` or `all`

Comment: no code as images please

Comment: Please edit your post by copy and pasting your code directly into the text :)

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

The problem here is that you misunderstood the conditional.

```
if ('?', '"', ',', '!') in x:
```

does not mean:

```
"If any of these appear in x"
```

It means "if this tuple of values" in x. It gives you an error because 'in' does not work with tuples on its left side. You need to break the tuple down into the values...
You could do:

```
char = ['?', '"', ',', '!']
if any((c in x) for c in char):
    #do stuff
```

This loops through each value individually and checks if they are in x. At the first sight of a value being in x, the condition will evaluate to True and proceed into your code block.

Comment: What do you mean by `in` does not work with tuples. The problem can be simply solved by interchanging the values in the condition to `if x in ('?', '"', ',', '!')` rest of the answer is an overkill

Comment: No...It can't. That is logically unsound. X is a larger string. Unless X were === any of those characters it would evaluate to false. What I meant to point out is that tuples cannot be to the left of "in".

Comment: Again I do not agree with your statement of left and right as it is misleading. tuple can exist on the left hand side of `in` operator as well given the right hand side is an iterable. For example `('1','2') in [('1','2') ]` is a valid statement. Hope it helps.

Comment: You're right that a `list` of `tuple`s can exist on the left hand side of the operator. That's not too relevant here though, especially since `[('1', '2')] in x` won't do what OP wants it do to anyways.